# How to implement the parse tree?

Tags: parsing, compilation, compiler-construction

I started writing a DBMS as a learning project, and now I'm implementing the lexer/parser for the language used in the DBMS.
I'm learning on my own from various different resources, and managed to write the lexer and the grammar for the language, but I'm stuck at writing the code to generate the parse tree.

Every time I google parsers I only get results on how to construct the parse tree by hand (showing you diagrams and whatnot) but no actual code on how to implement it.

Here's the repo for my project

https://github.com/abdulaziz-sama/accounting_db

The grammar is written in the comments in parser.h

The way I'm thinking of solving this problem is by writing a struct for each production, something like:

```
struct production {
non-terminal_1* x;
non_terminal_2* y;
terminal z; 
};
```

and use them as node in the a tree, but I'm not sure if this is the right way or if there are better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using plain C and not C++.

There are many ways. One simple possibility is to define generic tagged N-tuple structures similar to the memory layout of the ML-style languages:

```
struct _tuple2 {
    uint32_t tag;
    void* elt[2];
};

struct _tuple3 {
    uint32_t tag;
    void* elt[3];
};

// and so on
```

And so on, you've got the idea. You'll have to define boxed versions of simple data (integers, floats, strings, etc.) too. Implement macros for accessing tuple elements. Ideally, encode the number of elements of N-tuple in the tag itself.

This way you don't have a rigid data type for your parse tree, so making changes to it is easier. You can also define a dynamic-ish DSL for pattern matching these data structures, which will make your code much less convoluted.